# Write a logic to flag=1 if any one of the rows match per group (MID)? in SAS

Tags: sas

if any one of the observation has a match between MID_A and MID_B then New_Match=1

```
Input
MID_A.   MID_B.  Match
331.    331.       1
331.    331.       1
331.    331.       1
331.     .         0

Output
MID_A.   MID_B.  New_Match
331.    331.       1
```

Code:

```
data want;
 set have;
 by MID_B
  if MID_B=MID_A then do;
    New_Match=1;
  end;
run;
```

Comment: I'm not sure to look for each row per MID and if any of the row has a match then New_match=1. At present the code Flags it as 0 bcoz it found a mismatch at row #4

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SAS then an SQL solution is simple because PROC SQL will re-merge aggregate results back onto all observations in the group.

Since SAS evaluates Boolean expressions to 1 (TRUE) or 0 (FALSE) you can use the MAX() aggregate function to test if the test is ever true.

```
proc sql;
  create table output as
    select *, max(mid_a=mid_b) as Match
    from input
    group by mid_a
  ;
quit;
```

If you want to do it with a data step then use two DO loops.  The first DO loop will calculate the Match variable.  The second will re-read all of the observations in the group so they can be output.

The data will need to be sorted by the grouping variable(s).

```
data output ;
  do until (last.mid_a);
    set input ;
    by mid_a;
    Match=max(Match, mid_a=mid_b);
  end;
  do until (last.mid_a);
    set input ;
    by mid_a;
    output;
  end;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem, you need to create a lookup table of all cases where `Mid_A = Mid_B`, then set `New_Match = 1` if `Mid_A` from `have` is found in the lookup table. Here are two methods to do it that do not require pre-sorting the data.

SQL:

```
proc sql;
    create table want as
        select t1.Mid_A
             , t1.Mid_B
             , (t1.Mid_A = t2.Mid_A) as New_Match
        from have as t1
        LEFT JOIN
             (select distinct Mid_A
              from have
              where Mid_A = Mid_B
             ) as t2
        ON t1.Mid_A = t2.Mid_A
    ;
quit;
```

Data Step hash table:

```
data want;
    set have;
    
    if(_N_ = 1) then do;
        dcl hash h(dataset: 'have(where=(Mid_A = Mid_B))');
            h.defineKey('Mid_A');
        h.defineDone();
    end;
    
    New_Match = (h.Check() = 0);     
run;
```

```
MID_A   MID_B  Match
331.    331.       1
331.    331.       1
331.    331.       1
331.     .         1
```

Comment: They are not duplicates they are unique with other variable values.

Also, I cannot subset the data its one of the logic applied with other steps to bring the final output.

Comment: If you want to only create a table with matches as described in your desired output, then you'll query it where `MID_A = MID_B` and ignore the rest.

Comment: if first.MID and last.MID and Match=1 then do;
  New_Match=1;
end;

I know this piece is not correct but I have to run through each row to look for matches if just one row per group is 1 I will still flag as 1. I created match in the code to indicate if there is a match between MID_A=MID_B then Match=1 per row.

Comment: Right. If you are looking for the case where `Mid_A = Mid_B`, why not filter directly to those cases? Do you want to set the entire group as 1? And when you say group, do you just mean `Mid_A`? What defines a group? Please edit your original question with more details.

Comment: data want;
 set have;
 by MID_B
  if MID_B=MID_A then do;
    Match=1;
  end;
if Match=1 then do;
New_match=1;
end;
run

My question when I filter with Match=1 is it doing by each group (MID_A). Yes! MID_A is the group I'm referring here!